# Firefox Temporarily Freezing on Most Web Page Load (NS_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY)

Tags: firefox, out-of-memory

Frequently when I browse to a webpage in Firefox 3.6, the browser will freeze while loading (often the google analytics portion of a page). After about 15 seconds, it will give me the following message:

```
A script on the page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. You can stop the script now, or you continue to see if the script will complete.
```

It then presents me with two options "Stop Script" and "Continue".

If I click "Stop Script", it presents the following message:

```
Error: Component returned failure code: 0x8007000e (NS_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY)
[nsIXPCComponents_Utils.evalInSandbox]
```

I can then view the page as normal.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

Jack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable your Craigslist Addon. This worked for me.

I hope this helped.

D

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, a script associated with that web page isn't functioning well. Is it javascript, or something else? The error also isn't specific enough to identify exactly what is failing.

The NS_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY weakly implies that the script is caught in an endless loop. (Each iteration of the loop takes another bit of memory, until the sandbox fills up.)

If you're familiar with scripting, you can get the [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) plugin for Firefox. Firebug will allow you to examine and debug the script, and might lead to the specific error.

Good luck!
dafydd